# How to update this Svelte store without recreate it every time?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

Here the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/56770fec88af4b76bdc8ea962178854e?version=3.42.1

Here the code:

App.svelte:

```html
<script>
    import {editableStore} from "./store";
    
    let name = "John"

    $: player = editableStore(name);
</script>

<h1>Hello {$player.name}!</h1>

<button on:click={() => name = (name === "Bob" ? "Jerry" : "Bob")}>
    Change name
</button>

<h2>Log:</h2>

{#each $player.log as log}
    <li>{log}</li>
{/each}
```

store.js:

```js
import {writable} from "svelte/store";

const defaultStore = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 18,
    log: []
};

export const editableStore = (name) => {
    console.log("Recreated with name:", name);

    const {subscribe, update} = writable({...defaultStore}, () => () => clearInterval);

    if (name) {
        update(s => ({...s, name}));
    }

    const clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
        update(s => ({...s, log: [...s.log, new Date()]}))
    }, 1000)

    return { subscribe };
};
```

As you can see if you click on "Change name" the store gets recreated.

This is what I need to avoid.

**But how?**

Comment: You should follow the Svelte store tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores

Answer (score 7):

Instead of re-creating the store every time `name` changes, only create it once and set `$player.name` when `name` changes.

```svelte
<script>
    import {editableStore} from "./store";
    
    let name = "John";

    let player = editableStore(name);
    $: $player.name = name;
</script>
```

This will require you to update your store method to return the `set` function.

```js
export const editableStore = (name) => {
    console.log("Recreated with name:", name);

    // also destructure set here
    const {subscribe, update, set} = writable({...defaultStore}, () => () => clearInterval);

    if (name) {
        update(s => ({...s, name}));
    }

    const clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
        update(s => ({...s, log: [...s.log, new Date()]}))
    }, 1000)

    // also return set here
    return { subscribe, set };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to instanciate your store as son as possible like in the `./store.js` file  and then use the `set` or `update` method instead of instanciate it in the component directly:

```js
// store.js

import {writable} from "svelte/store";

const defaultStore = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 18,
    log: []
};

export const createEditableStore = () => {
    const {subscribe, update, set} = writable({...defaultStore}, () => () => clearInterval);

    const clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
        update(s => ({...s, log: [...s.log, new Date()]}))
    }, 1000)

    return { subscribe, set, update };
};

export const player = createEditableStore()
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->

<script>
    import { player } from "./store";
    
    let name = "John"

    $: player.update(p => ({ ...p, name }))
</script>

<h1>Hello {$player.name}!</h1>

<button on:click={() => name = (name === "Bob" ? "Jerry" : "Bob")}>
    Change name
</button>

<h2>Log:</h2>

{#each $player.log as log}
    <li>{log}</li>
{/each}
```

Have a look at the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/beb19431ca794b9c987273d2a5e6343e?version=3.42.1).